# XMLParser after parsing gives NULL values in dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the XML to json format. I use the XMLReader third party library (which downloaded from Github). After Parsing the xml I get the NULL Results. 
 I tried to print the NSError values which gives the error is "NSErrorDomain code =4 and Document is Empty". What can i do? can any one to help this?

- **Here is my ViewDidLoad () Code:**

  ```
    NSDictionary *xmlDict =  [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

     NSError *parseError = nil;

      xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:@"abc.xml"];  // which call's the XMLReader Class Method

     NSLog(@"MAIN CLASS OF Dictionary: %@",xmlDict);  // Gives the NULL Results.
  ```
- **Here is my XMLReader.h Code**

  ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface XMLReader : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
        {
          NSMutableArray *dictionaryStack;
          NSMutableString *textInProgress;
           NSError *errorPointer;
          }

         + (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
         + (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)errorPointer;

            @end
  ```

  - **Here is my XMLReader.m Code**

    ```
         #import "XMLReader.h"

            NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"text";

               @interface XMLReader (Internal)

             - (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error;
              - (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data;

                @end

               @implementation XMLReader

                 #pragma mark -
                 #pragma mark Public methods

                + (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
                  {
                  XMLReader *reader = [[XMLReader alloc] initWithError:error];
                   NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [reader objectWithData:data];

                 return rootDictionary;
                    }

               + (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)error
                  {
                   NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    return [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:error];
                       }

               #pragma mark Parsing

                  - (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data
                        {
                        // Clear out any old data

                           dictionaryStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                          textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

                            // Initialize the stack with a fresh dictionary
                             [dictionaryStack addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

                          // Parse the XML
                           NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
                            parser.delegate = self;
                             BOOL success = [parser parse];

                     // Return the stack's root dictionary on success
                  if (success)
                   {
                      NSDictionary *resultDict = [dictionaryStack objectAtIndex:0];
                      return resultDict;
                      }

                  return nil;
                }

           #pragma mark NSXMLParserDelegate methods

            - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
              {
             // Get the dictionary for the current level in the stack
                NSMutableDictionary *parentDict = [dictionaryStack lastObject];

               // Create the child dictionary for the new element, and initilaize it with the attributes
                 NSMutableDictionary *childDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                  [childDict addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];

                    // If there's already an item for this key, it means we need to create an array
                     id existingValue = [parentDict objectForKey:elementName];
                  if (existingValue)
                  {
                      NSMutableArray *array = nil;
                     if ([existingValue isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
                       {
                           // The array exists, so use it
                              array = (NSMutableArray *) existingValue;
                        }
                          else
                             {
                      // Create an array if it doesn't exist
                       array = [NSMutableArray array];
                       [array addObject:existingValue];

                      // Replace the child dictionary with an array of children dictionaries
                          [parentDict setObject:array forKey:elementName];
                        }

                      // Add the new child dictionary to the array
                       [array addObject:childDict];
                     }
                  else
                    {
                    // No existing value, so update the dictionary
                        [parentDict setObject:childDict forKey:elementName];
                        }

                   // Update the stack
                      [dictionaryStack addObject:childDict];
                       }

                   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
                     {
                     // Update the parent dict with text info
                         NSMutableDictionary *dictInProgress = [dictionaryStack lastObject];

                // Set the text property
                   if ([textInProgress length] > 0)
                       {
                            [dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];

              // Reset the text

                 textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
               }

                     // Pop the current dict
                        [dictionaryStack removeLastObject];
                }

               - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
                 {
                    // Build the text value
                         [textInProgress appendString:string];
                   }

                           - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
                    {
                           // Set the error pointer to the parser's error object
                         errorPointer = parseError;
                          NSLog(@"ERROR PONIT IS:  %@",errorPointer);
                       }

              @end
    ```

So, In this code i use for parsing the xml data to dictionary format. Can any one to help me on this issue?

Comment: You are getting error because you need to pass the XML string not the url.

Comment: Thanks for Replay Nirav. Could u explain how to use XML url inside this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Decalre below method in AppDelegate.h file

```
+(void)downloadDataFromURL:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSData *data))completionHandler;
```

Add the method definition in AppDelegate.m File

```
+(void)downloadDataFromURL:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *))completionHandler{
// Instantiate a session configuration object.
      NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

// Instantiate a session object.
      NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

// Create a data task object to perform the data downloading.
      NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        // If any error occurs then just display its description on the console.
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        // If no error occurs, check the HTTP status code.
        NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        // If it's other than 200, then show it on the console.
        if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %d", HTTPStatusCode);
        }

        // Call the completion handler with the returned data on the main thread.
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            completionHandler(data);
        }];
    }
}];
}
```

Now Call this method from your viewController like this in viewDidload

```
[AppDelegate downloadDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data) {
    // Make sure that there is data.
    if (data != nil) {
        xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:&parseError];
    }
}];
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Have you try my answer?